# Позиционирование div`ов с использованием "display: flex"

Tags: html, css

Есть родительский контейнер с заданным CSS правилом `display: flex`.

Также есть 3 дочерних элемента. Надо спозиционировать их так, чтобы первый элемент был наверху, второй - по центру, а третий - снизу.

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* flex: 0 0 100px; */
    height: 100%;
}

.container .one, .container .two, .container .three{
    width: 90%;
    height: 90px;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="one">1</div>
    <div class="two">2</div>
    <div class="three">3</div>
</div>
```

[Пример в fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0k68pfg1/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задайте родителю justify-content: space-between; свойство вызывает именно описанное вами поведение дочерних элементов